# Loading pcap file in spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, pcap

I am new to Spark. I have pcap file. How can Spark read that file using python? How can I upload pcap file in Spark using python and how can it process?

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkStreamingPcap")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
FileLog = sc.textFile("pcapFiles/ipv4frags.pcap")
df = FileLog.map(lambda line: line.split("\n"))
print("Helloo")
print (df.count())
```

Comment: have you written any code for us to see so we can help you.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have uploaded code snippet

Comment: 1. does the file exist in that location? 2. what is your expected output and what do you get now? any error?

Comment: I want to process pcap file. i want to get timeStamp and Ips. I am not getting any output

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using `dpkt` or `scapy` to parse pcap files in pyspark code.

Comment: True: indeed, you can’t read a pcap as text but as binary with its own format. You’ll have to implement magic handling and lots of stuff if not using an already existing API